# R Markdown won't Knit to PDF or Word

Tags: r-markdown, kableextra

When I try to knit to a pdf or do word, I get this error message:

```
processing file: E3---Markdown.Rmd
|.....                                              |  10% \[unnamed-chunk-1\]
Quitting from lines 12-25 \[unnamed-chunk-1\] (E3---Markdown.Rmd)
Error:
! package or namespace load failed for 'kableExtra':
.onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'kableExtra', details:
call: !is.null(rmarkdown::metadata$output) && rmarkdown::metadata$output %in%
error: 'length = 3' in coercion to 'logical(1)'
Backtrace:

1. base::library(kableExtra)
2. base::tryCatch(...)
3. base (local) tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
4. base (local) tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers\[\[1L\]\])
5. value\[\[3L\]\](cond)

Execution halted\
```

The referenced lines 12-25 are:

```
library(modelsummary)
library(tidyverse)
library(lmtest)
library(sandwich)
library(estimatr)
library(kableExtra)
library(vtable)

## Graph Stuff

cbPalette \<- c("#999999", "#E69F00", "#56B4E9", "#009E73", "#F0E442", "#0072B2", "#D55E00", "#CC79A7")
cbPalettet \<- c("#99999950", "#E69F0050", "#56B4E950", "#009E7350", "#F0E44250", "#0072B250", "#D55E0050", "#CC79A750")
```

I've tried clearing everything and reloading everything after restarting r studio.

I've tried not loading kableExtra and removing the code chunks that used it. Even when kableExtra wasn't loaded, the same error message appeared.

I'm too new to this to understand what it means.